# Create Android's mutable Bitmap from pixels array in NDK

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ndk

I need to do some `Bitmap` manipulation in native code. Specifically, my JNI set-up is something like this:

```
// pixels color array in ARGB_8888 format, returned by dependent library
char* pixels;
jobject bitmap = null /* what to put here */;
return bitmap;
```

I want to fill in the indicated line to return the `Bitmap` which is usable in my `Activity` **and** so that when I later modify the `pixels` in NDK, the `Bitmap` object returned here is automatically updated without re-creation or data copy. The intention is that `pixels` is updated over and over again. I am aware of `Bitmap.createBitmap` methods as in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html but the applicable methods seem to produce *immutable* bitmaps while the ones producing mutable bitmap do not allow me to put in my pixels data.

Answer (score 2):

I delved into Android source code (starting with `Bitmap.java` and its JNI counterpart) and managed to find the C++ class  [`GraphicsJNI`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/GraphicsJNI.h). The applicable method is

```
static SkBitmap* getNativeBitmap(JNIEnv*, jobject bitmap);
```

Apparently, each `Bitmap` stores a reference to a native C++ class [`SkBitmap`](https://github.com/android/platform_external_skia/blob/master/include/core/SkBitmap.h) and simply forward its methods to corresponding native ones. `SkBitmap` belongs to an external library [Skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/). From its interface, I can use `setPixels` method for my purpose. So the solution is:

```
#include <GraphicsJNI.h>
#include <SkBitmap.h>

char* pixels; // assume already exists
jobject bitmap; // construct an immutable bitmap in Java
SkBitmap* native_bitmap = GraphicsJNI::getNativeBitmap(env, bitmap);
native_bitmap->setPixels(pixels);
```

**Note**: This code needs to be linked with `libandroid_runtime.so` and `libskia.so`, both of which can be obtained from the emulator. This makes the code platform-dependent.

Comment: Does setPixels copy the data or take ownership of it?

Answer (score 0):

NDK provides special API to work natively with android [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), see https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap. The bitmap is "immutable", but you can [lock](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/bitmap#androidbitmap_lockpixels) its pixels and manipulate the content of the **void*** buffer you receive. Don't forget to **unlock()** the bitmap after you are ready.

Comment: The http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#bitmap link gives 404.

Comment: @SergeyPrigogin after 9 years, the link updated.